# Does KeePass have permanent inner master key to encrypt data?

Tags: keepass

Does KeePass have permanent **inner key** to encrypt data? Or the key for encryption **is** a password (and keyfile)?
On some website I've run eyes over the discusstion about ways to hack KeePass base. One of assumptions was that there are two ways: one to bruteforce the *passphrase* and other was about to bruteforce the encrypted *masterkey*. Is there is really permanent inner master key for data encryption?

Comment: it is open source, so everyone that cares can read the source code. If there is a master key in the source code, it would be public, and make the whole thing useless.

Comment: I mean master key which can be generated once at password base creation and is encrypted by user password (and keyfile).

Comment: That is what happens by default....

Comment: I don't understand... Do you mean that when password base is created, the master key is generated? If so is there a way to force KeePass change master key and re encrypt the base when changing user password? Imagine the situation when someone finds out the password, retreives master key. But base owner doesn't know about it and simply keep changing password base once in some period of time... Things aren't good then...

Answer (score 2):

After reading this [article](http://keepass.info/help/base/security.html) it seems that some random bytes are really generated, but only with the aim to complete full 256-bit key:

> In order to generate the 256-bit key for the block ciphers, the Secure
>   Hash Algorithm SHA-256 is used. This algorithm compresses the user key
>   provided by the user (consisting of password and/or key file) to a
>   fixed-size key of 256 bits. This transformation is one-way, i.e. it is
>   computationally infeasible to invert the hash function or find a
>   second message that compresses to the same hash.
>
> The recently discovered attack against SHA-1 [2] doesn't affect the
>   security of SHA-256. SHA-256 is still considered as being very secure
>   [3].
>
> **Key Derivation:**
>
> If only a password is used (i.e. no key file), the
>   password plus a 128-bit random salt are hashed using SHA-256 to form
>   the final key (but note there is some preprocessing: Protection
>   against Dictionary Attacks). The random salt prevents attacks that are
>   based on pre-computed hashes.
>
> When using both password and key file, the final key is derived as
>   follows: SHA-256(SHA-256(password), key file contents), i.e. the hash
>   of the master password is concatenated with the key file bytes and the
>   resulting byte string is hashed with SHA-256 again. If the key file
>   doesn't contain exactly 32 bytes (256 bits), they are hashed with
>   SHA-256, too, to form a 256-bit key. The formula above then changes
>   to: SHA-256(SHA-256(password), SHA-256(key file contents)).

So I make conclusion that **there is no** inner master key. When user password (and keyfile) is changed, password base is re encrypted with a new key.